# How to run c++11 codes in vim with cvim plugin?

Tags: vim

I have installed cvim plugin for vim in Ubuntu from this link :
http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/01/tutorial-make-vim-as-your-cc-ide-using-cvim-plugin/

Now I want to run c++11 standard programs in vim.How to configure vim so that it can compile and run c++11 programs ?

Answer (score 1):

The plugin defaults to `gcc` as the C compiler, configured by `g:C_VimCompilerName` (as per the [help](http://lug.fh-swf.de/vim/vim-c/csupport.html#csupport-run-buffer)). You need to have a compiler version installed that supports the new C++11 features.

To inquire about general plugin support for C++11 (e.g. in its snippets and other features), best directly ask the plugin author (the plugin page even references a mailing list), and ideally offer patches and your help.